# Segmentation fault in accessing legitimate memory address

Tags: c, linux, gdb, segmentation-fault

I'm having this weird scenario of `segmentation fault` while trying to get the data in a legitimate pointer. I've a `INTEGER` pointer named `p` and whenever I try to get the data in `p` using `*p`, I get segmentation fault.

I tried to find out the problem using `GDB`. While in `GDB`, the memory reference still throws `SIGSEGV` even though I can get the correct data using `print *p`

My code fragment is like follows:

```
int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
// some other codes
printf("%d\n", *p);
```

For sure `p` is not `NULL`. Because I checked for `NULL` before printing. But I can't be sure if it is pointing to some invalid location. Because the code in the middle is to big to find out. Is there any way I can check if it is pointing to random locations?

To be sure that it is not pointing to some random locations, I printed the address in `p` just after the `malloc` and before the `printf` statement and they seem to be same. So I think the address isn't random. Also `GDB print` gives me the correct data I'm expecting.

Comment: Without your code, we'll be shooting arrows in thin air. ;-)

Comment: So you have pointer. Why do you think it is pointing to something "legitimate" ? Probably it is null or just some random location.

Comment: Edited my question. It is part of a big program. The code above is only for giving a outline of whats happening. Any suggestion/help is appreciated.

Comment: Use printf, or use your debugger, to inspect the value of p after the malloc.  Use printf, or debugger, to inspect the value of p before dereferencing p in the printf.  Are they the same?

Comment: @MartinJames yes, they are same. Forgot to add that in my question. Edited

Comment: Can you show us the backtrace that gdb prints?

Comment: If everything in the comments is true, the problem is elsewhere, so more information needed. Anyway, voting to reopen the question, hopin you will improve it.

Comment: you should try to make a proper [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).  That means making a new project which actually demonstrates the problem, but contains only the code needed to reproduce the problem, and no hidden code, such as `// some other codes`.  That way, we can be confident that the problem doesn't lie in some other code that you haven't posted

Comment: What if you remove the `printf` line, will the rest work properly? What if you replace `*p` in `printf` by something else (number, for instance) ?

Comment: @SamIam I can understand that. Problem is, it is part of a big project. I surely can understand that the problem might be in some parts of the hidden code. That's why I post the question here to get some suggestion from someone who might have faced the problem before. Obviously creating a simple program to do the above things will work.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The original code depends on the value of *p. So it doesn't matter If I remove the printf or not.

Comment: Well, what happens if you comment out all of 'some other codes'?  If that works, what happens if you comment out only half of 'some other codes'?  The other half?  Keep chopping at it.

Comment: @azizulhakim If it doesn't then the problem is obviously not in the lines presented. So the question is starting to loose it's sense once again.

Comment: ^^ what @EugeneSh.says.  You seem to have posted code where you are sure the problem is not....

Comment: @EugeneSh. the printf statement is only for debugging purpose. In the original code, I've to do some computation based on value of *p. And I was having the SIGSEGV at this computation while I was trying to get the data from *p. So I added a printf instruction just before that computation to be sure that the problem is with the pointer. And now the SIGSEGBV occurs in the printf statement.

Comment: So put the printf before the "some other codes", to see it is not the problem.

Comment: @EugeneSh. don't think that's possible. It is a big project with a lot of source files and functions. I myself don't know the flow of the functions. I was just playing with the features implemented and faced this problem. I was expecting someone might have faced something like this and could suggest me something. Seems I have to debug more and find out myself. I'll put my findings if something interesting comes up.

Comment: Set a breakpoint after the `p=malloc(...)` statement. Give gdb the command `watch p`, then continue. Is anything unexpected being written to `p`?

Answer (score 0):

> I printed the address in p just after the malloc and before the printf statement and they seem to be same.

How hard can it be to be *absolutely* sure that they are the same?

Seriously, you need a rational approach instead of saying "help, I have tons of code, and I have no idea where the problem might be" -- nobody could help you given that info either.

So what are some rational things you could do?

You could start inserting `printf("ZZZZ %s: %d: %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, *p);` *everywhere*. That `printf` will not crash immediately after `malloc`, but at some point it will. Congratulations: you've just narrowed the problem.

A *faster* approach might be to run your program under [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) or [AddressSanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/AddressSanitizer): these tools often lead you straight to the problem.

As to what the problem actually is, I *suspect* that your `malloc` is actually allocating a few MBytes of data rather than the 4 bytes you've shown, and for such a large chunk glibc will call `mmap`. If you `free` that data later, glibc will `munmap` the chunk, and make the memory inaccessible. Next time you try to print `*p` (which would access a *dangling* pointer), you get a segmentation fault.

Comment: Yes I know how to debug. Turns out the function was hooked at run time. The hook was inserted from some rather unrelated source which made it difficult for debug. Could only figure it out once I contacted the developer and he pointed to the possible reason

Comment: @azizulhakim "I know how to debug. Could only figure it out ... when he pointed to ..." These two sentences contradict each other.